# Deserialising IEnumerable<> with BinaryFormatter - error / odd behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, ienumerable, binaryformatter

I have an assembly that saves and loads (or tries to) an IEnumerable<> to/from a persisted binary stream.

If the assembly is loaded, and a serialisation of the data is performed before a deserialisation, everything works fine and the data is deserialised and loaded as expected, with no exceptions thrown.

However, if the assembly is loaded and a request is made to deserialise the (persisted) data before serialisation occurs, the following error is generated:

```
The MyClass could not be transferred.
Unable to load type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[MyClass, MyAssembly, 
Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] required for deserialization.
```

i have read many articles on serialising ienumerables and i am somewhat confused by what i have read, as many sources state it should not be possible, but this code has apparently worked in the past (i have since moved some types between assemblies (which appears to be the cause of the issue) but i cant move them back).

why does it only work if the serialisation takes places first? why cant it find the type if serialisation doesnt occur? why do i not get this error on serialisation?

---

```
public void Load<T>(T instance)
{
    Transfer(instance, (binaryFormatter, property, key, inst) =>
        {
            object value = PropertyBag.Read(key);

            if(null != value)
            {
                using(MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(value as byte[]))
                {
                    property.SetValue(inst, binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream), null);
                }
            }
        });
}

public void Save<T>(T instance)
{
    Transfer(instance, (binaryFormatter, property, key, inst) =>
        {
            object value = property.GetValue(inst, null);

            using(MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, value);
                PropertyBag.Write(key, memoryStream.GetBuffer());
            }
        });
}

internal sealed class AssemblyBinder : SerializationBinder
{
    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        Type typeDefinition = null;

        Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

        try
        {
            string isolatedAssemblyName = assemblyName.Split(',')[0];

            foreach(Assembly assembly in assemblies)
            {
                if(assembly.FullName.Split(',')[0] == isolatedAssemblyName)
                {
                    typeDefinition = assembly.GetType(typeName);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(System.Exception ex)
        {
            LogManager.Logger.Log(new LoggableException(ex));
        }

        return typeDefinition;
    }
}

private void Transfer<T>(T instance, Action<BinaryFormatter, PropertyInfo, string, T> action)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties(
        GetBindingFlags());

    foreach(PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        try
        {
            BaggableAttribute[] attributes =
                property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(BaggableAttribute), true) 
                    as BaggableAttribute[];

            if(attributes == null || attributes.Length == 0)
                continue;

            BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            binaryFormatter.Binder = new AssemblyBinder();

            action.Invoke(binaryFormatter, property, attributes[0].Key, instance);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Log(new PropertyTransferException(ex, property.Name));
        }
    }
}

private BindingFlags GetBindingFlags()
{
    return BindingFlags.Public |
        BindingFlags.NonPublic |
        BindingFlags.Instance;
}
```

---

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Nothing worse than silence in response to a question, so... Carefully consider not just "MyClass" but also all types that its properties reference. Do any of those types come from an assembly having a version number that changed between serialization and deserialization? Do any of those types come from an assembly having a strong name that was recompiled between serialization and deserialization? Either of the above would cause an exception upon deserialization. Also, to help isolate the issue, you might do a little experimentation without using generics.

Comment: Thank you for replying :) i ended up working around the problem by just using arrays instead of generics - this allowed the code to work as expected, but didn't shed any light on the behaviour described in the initial post, which still stumps me.. the only thing i can think of is that the clr is caching the types it see's somewhere and is inspecting this list when it needs to deserialise..

Comment: You can not deserialize something and get something with an interface as type. You can only deserialize to a type that has an accessibe constructor, but an interface has no constructor. This means you can get back a List<T> or an array T[] but never an IEnumerable<T>.